# Cannot find resource EntityModel.rlinq embedded in assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity

I am trying to run a solution which has entity model included but I am getting weird error which someone already had in the past and can help me solve this. My colleague says that the solution is running fine on his comp and on other computers too, but on mine comp doesn't want to work for some reason. Please let me know if I am missing something, he checked too, and it looks pretty much the same. 
Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Every advice is welcome.
Thanks, Laziale

Answer (score 3):

It seems you do not have OpenAccess ORM installed on your machine. You can refer [this article](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/external-tools-howto-integrate-enhancer-msbuild.html), which demonstrates how to use OpenAccess ORM without installing.

If this is not the case and you have the product installed, you need to verify whether the OpenAccess.targets file is deployed under the MSBuild folder [C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild] and it tries to resolve the enhancer from the correct location. Additionally the Build Action for the rlinq file should be set to OpenAccessDeploy.

Answer (score 0):

if `telerik 2015 q1` is used, this issue comes. first check whether `openaccess.target.dll` is present in the path `c:/program files(86)/msbuild.` if not, place the one. then install `telerik q1` installer. I got the installer from my team mate as it is not available in `telerik` site(deprecated)
.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue [this Offical Telerik post](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/data-access/details/handling-error-cannot-find-resource-entitydiagrams-rlinq-embedded-in-assembly) helped me.

TLDR:

> 1. In Solution Explorer right-click the project containing the rlinq and select Unload Project.
> 2. Right-click on the unloaded project and select Edit ProjectName.csproj (vbproj).
> 3. Add this to the end of your file:
>
>    ```
>    <Import Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\OpenAccess.targets')" Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\OpenAccess.targets" />
>    ```